# Append/edit JSON file at runtime in iOS5

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2, nsjsonserialization

I have JSON file which has names and details. I want to edit JSON file at runtime as user adds a new name in iPhone application at client side. This means the name should be added in the JSON file when the user adds a name. Is this possible ... and how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial for parsing JSON http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5.

[Apple documentation is also good](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

To be short — you first read JSON to JSON object, then create additional NSDictionary objects, add your data to according dictionaries and then write to JSON object.